# Custom logic before controller Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

My business is studying moving from Struts to Spring MVC. We have a large set of web applications which uses the same base layer of custom logic before any application specific controller (called Action in Struts). In Struts we deal with this by having a few classes which extends the Action class. Then the webapps extends those custom classes.

I trying to find the *good* way to achieve the same result with Spring MVC (latest version 4.3.4). From what I see **handler interceptor** doesn't quite fit my needs. The custom logic that need to be executed can't be determined by requestMapping.

Is there a way to create a custom annotation like @ControllerCustomA and @ControllerCustomB instead of @Controller that would check stuff, log, etc.

and then have

```java
//check authentication, for instance
@ControllerA
public class user{
    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String getUser() {
        //application specific logic
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's checking authentication, for instance, then you want to use spring-security annotations. If it's something more generic, use generic spring-aop.

Comment: @OrangeDog It's not only that, but yeah there's authentication. I've been looking into Spring-security, however it's going to be complicated to blend our system with it, even with custom UserServiceDetails...

Comment: @Nikolai could you please enumerate your use cases?

Comment: Can't you just add a Filter before the controller and put your logic there?

Comment: @KamillSokol For instance, we need to to check objects in session, log in activity, do custom DB authentication which really doesn't fit Spring-Security, at least not without heavy changes my businnes can't afford. Also we load menus and stuff given the user authorizations and so on. It's pretty extensive, and we have different controller behaviours...I'm looking at aspectj right now, and think it might help. Not sure how to use it though

Comment: What do you mean by _different controller behaviours_? Spring is very flexible and you can build almost any application with it. I don't know your application domain so I can give you just pointers. Did you study the documentation especially the web part? For instance, `@ModelAttribute` in conjuction with `@ControllerAdvice` might be a good fit for your application. It allows you to put common data into the model map for every request as well as user specific data like username or granted roles, etc.

Comment: @KamillSokol Thx for your answer. I think I overlooked `@ControllerAdvice` and  `@ModelAttribute` before, and it does seem suitable for Handling errors and set default data. However I don't see how this would allow me to do execute custom authentication, putting attributes in the request session and so on...

Comment: @Nikolai How do you authenticate your users right now? I think there is a login page somewhere in the application? You can do that with Spring MVC or with Spring Security. You can inject the `HttpSession` into your request handler method or you can use `@SessionAttributes` to put data into the session (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-methods.

Comment: @KamillSokol that's exactly what is done. Without SpringSecurity obviously. it's more about checking authentication actually & fetching menus compliant with its authorizations. This data is not preloaded in session for performance issues (we handle a lot of connections at peak moments). I'm really digging Aspects right now, I think I'll combine it with `@ControllerAdvice` to handle errors and general purpose logging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your place I'd use an [aspect](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html).

You can configure it to intercept only methods in classes with some annotations.

Take a look at http://blog.javaforge.net/post/76125490725/spring-aop-method-interceptor-annotation

Comment: Thx, I've been digging it, and it really fits my needs. Custom annotation and aspects combined as such a powerful tool. I feel bad I only discovering this now...